# Iterating over two dataframes to apply a function

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following two dataframes (shortened):

```
df1
day Transmitter_ID  Species Lat Lng Date
4   A69-1601-27466  Golden perch    -35.495479100000004 144.45295380000002  13/08/2015
5   A69-1601-27466  Golden perch    -35.495479100000004 144.45295380000002  14/08/2015
6   A69-1601-27466  Golden perch    -35.495479100000004 144.45295380000002  15/08/2015
7   A69-1601-27466  Golden perch    -35.495479100000004 144.45295380000002  16/08/2015
8   A69-1601-27466  Golden perch    -35.5065473 144.4488804 17/08/2015
8   A69-1601-27466  Golden perch    -35.495479100000004 144.45295380000002  17/08/2015
9   A69-1601-27466  Golden perch    -35.5065473 144.4488804 18/08/2015
10  A69-1601-27466  Golden perch    -35.5065473 144.4488804 19/08/2015
11  A69-1601-27466  Golden perch    -35.5065473 144.4488804 20/08/2015
12  A69-1601-27466  Golden perch    -35.5065473 144.4488804 21/08/2015
13  A69-1601-27466  Golden perch    -35.5065473 144.4488804 22/08/2015
14  A69-1601-27466  Golden perch    -35.5065473 144.4488804 23/08/2015
15  A69-1601-27466  Golden perch    -35.5065473 144.4488804 24/08/2015

rivergps_df
Lng Lat River
151.7753278 -32.90526725    HUNTER RIVER
151.77526830000002  -32.90610052    HUNTER RIVER
151.77526830000002  -32.90752299    HUNTER RIVER
151.77526830000002  -32.90758849    HUNTER RIVER
151.775397  -32.90977754    HUNTER RIVER
151.7754468 -32.91062396    HUNTER RIVER
151.775578  -32.91202941    HUNTER RIVER
151.77578799999998  -32.9142797 HUNTER RIVER
151.7758178 -32.91459931    HUNTER RIVER
151.77586340000002  -32.91508789    HUNTER RIVER
151.7764116 -32.91645856    HUNTER RIVER
151.7765776 -32.91687345    HUNTER RIVER
151.77719040000002  -32.91861786    HUNTER RIVER
```

I also have a haversine function that takes a pair of lat, lng and returns a distance between the two pairs

```
def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
```

What I want to do with the two dataframes is:

Take each lng / lat from df1 and for each point, apply the haversine function for the whole range of lng / lat from rivergps_df

Return the index of rivergps_df where the minimum for the haversine function occurred

Append this rivergps_df index to df1

So what I mean is for the first point in df1 -35.495479100000004, 144.45295380000002, I want to apply the haversine function to this as lon1, lat1 against lon2, lat2 where lon2, lat2 is all points that exists in rivergps_df. I then want to find the minimum returned by the haversine function, append it to df1 and move to the next point in df1.

How would I do this?

Comment: `apply` could be the functions for it.. look into it please...

Answer (score 0):

One idea:

- Define a function `haversin_argmin(lat, lon, df)` that iterates over `df` (e.g. `for (lat2, lon2) df[['Lat', 'Lon']].iterrows():`) and computes and returns the `argmin` for `haversine(lat, lon, lat2, lon2)`.
- Then define another function `f` that takes a `row`, gets the `lat` and `lon`, calls `haversin_argmin` with `rivergps_df`, and returns `row` with the `argmin` appended as a new field.
- Use [pandas.DataFrame.apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to `apply` `f` to `df1`.

Read the documentation for `apply` to better understand how to define `f` and what options to pass to `apply`.